# How to pass ordinary function imported from another namespace as callable?

Tags: php, namespaces, php-7

Let's say that I have this import statement:

```
use function A\B\C\fun;
```

Then I could use `fun` like that:

```
$result = fun($something);
```

Now I would like to pass that `fun` to another function/method that expect `callable`, eg:

```
$other_array = array_map('fun', $some_array);
$other_array = array_map('A\B\C\fun', $some_array);
```

Neither of those will work. PHP claim that `fun` is unrecognized, even though if called directly by either of those syntax variants `fun` will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're relying on an autoloader to `include` the actual file in which the function is defined… unfortunately autoloaders only kick into gear when trying to use undefined *classes or interfaces*, not functions. You'll have to `include` the relevant file by hand first.

Comment: Yeah knowing the actual error message would help troubleshoot this a lot, eh?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d4730e2ca0af0ef77b29f4cb49296b3f93a3d981) seems to work:

```
<?php

namespace A\B\C {
    function doubler($i) {
        return $i *= 2;
    }

}

namespace D {

    $doubled = array_map('A\B\C\doubler', [1,2,3]);    

    echo json_encode($doubled);

}
```

Output:
`[2,4,6]`

But that sounds like what you tried? Not sure what the difference is. If you included the error, it might help